# Form elements with digestive-functors

Tags: haskell, digestive-functors

Digestive-functors-blaze creates html like `<input type="text" id="foo" name="foo" /><label for="foo">Bar</label>`, but I didn't find any standard way to for example add `<br />` to the end.

I came up with this:

```
br :: (Monad m) => HappstackForm m H.Html BlazeFormHtml ()
br = Common.label $ \_ -> do
  createFormHtml $ \cfg -> do
    H.br
```

I can append it with `<++` which does what I expect it to, but I wonder whether this is the intended way?

Also how would this extend with for example fieldsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended way, although `br` would be a little cleaner when written as:

```
br :: Monad m
   => Form m i e BlazeFormHtml ()
br = view $ createFormHtml $ const H.br
```

Anyway, I figured this definition is a little cumbersome so I added a `viewHtml` function to `Text.Digestive.Forms.Html`:

```
viewHtml :: Monad m => a -> Form m i e (FormHtml a) ()
viewHtml = view . createFormHtml . const
```

This is available in [digestive-functors-0.1.0.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors-0.1.0.1). Using this new combinator, you should be able to just use `<++ viewHtml H.br` — I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to see how fieldsets work and I'll mark this as an answer afterwards